# Please help me identify book chronicling life of titular character turns out to be computer printed summary of his life

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov, computers

Language: English.

I read this some time in the late 80s / early 90s. The author must have had a Commodore 64 computer, because printouts from the mainframe computer in the story (which bears similarities to Asimov's Multivac) tend to end with text like this:

```
READY.
READY.
READY.
READY.
```

The title is a single word, which is the name of the main protagonist; I think it started with C, like COSMO or CHARLIE or CARL or the like.

At one point, a friend of his dies, and our protagonist is startled at how the computer prints out a beautifully detailed summary of his friend's life, including his innermost thoughts, ending with the `READY. READY. ...` prompt.

The big twist is that the last page of the book ends with

```
READY.
READY.
READY.
READY.
```

... and you realize that the entire detailed, personal account you have been reading is just another life summary from the computer.

Does anyone recognize the book?

Comment: My first thought was David Gerrold's [*When H.A.R.L.I.E Was One,*](http://www.gerrold.com/book/when-harlie-was-one/) but I'm pretty sure that's not the story you're looking for; the ending is completely different.

Comment: @JoeL. Thanks - but you are right; that is not it.

Comment: Not what I was thinking. There's a story from teh 60s about a rich Texas rancher who uses a massive computer to try and see if the "infinite Monkeys will write Shakespeare" experiment can really be done; His friend and neighbor discovers this after the first rancher publishes a brilliant novel under his own name, actually written by the machine. The end comes when the output begins to tell the very story itself at the end.